# Prevent the Autocomplete to work in the web form

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a form in one of my pages that I want to prevent it being filled by the Autocomplete(Google Docs, Last Pass, etc.) I know the user can turn off the autocomplete by themselves, however, it is hard to make sure all customer do this so I wonder if there is a way to make the form unfillable by the browser(modify the html code, javascript, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Add the property `autocomplete` to the field

```
<input autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

turn off autocomplete on the form element
 `<form autocomplete="off">`

Although alot of browsers ignore this flag, so a way to prevent that would be to dynamically add `readonly` to the inputs and remove it on click.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the attribute 
    autocomplete ='off'
 in your form tag or any particular input tags.